# select all field from one table and one from another table in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i need to select all field from one table without specifying them, and only one field from another table in joining query, but am getting errors.

**here is my code.**

```
SELECT  staff_research.*, research_details.type
     FROM  staff_research,research_details
         INNER JOIN research_details  staff_research
               ON research_details.id = staff_research.rid
```

**the error am getting**

```
Unknown column 'staff_research.rid' in 'on clause'
```

i don't know what i am missing, any help please!

Comment: Please provide structure & data of both table.

Comment: Add table structure to fing mapping columns

Comment: I gave you a -1 for your writing quality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove `research_details` table from the `From` clause,

```
SELECT  staff_research.*, research_details.type
FROM  staff_research
INNER JOIN research_details 
ON research_details.id = staff_research.rid
```

**Reference**: [*JOIN SYNTAX*](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html)

Comment: Should remove staff_research from inner join too.

Comment: @Devon - Thanks devon & sharsh.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT sr.*, rd.type
FROM staff_research sr 
INNER JOIN research_details rd ON rd.id = sr.rid;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

Your syntax of `INNER JOIN` is not correct.
Please improve it using following syntax.

```
SELECT  staff_research.*, research_details.type
FROM  staff_research
INNER JOIN research_details ON research_details.id = staff_research.rid
```

Answer (score 0):

You use: INNER JOIN research_details  staff_research <-> research_details as staff_research 
-> error